# Why is the __init__ method of Counter referred to as a descriptor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-datamodel

I was reading the __init__ method of the Counter class, and saw this:

```
if not args:
    TypeError("descriptor '__init__' of 'Counter' object "
              "needs an argument")
```

I wasn't sure what it meant by descriptor, so I checked the python data model document and found this:

> In general, a descriptor is an object attribute with “binding behavior”, one whose attribute access has been overridden by methods in the descriptor protocol: __get__(), __set__(), and __delete__(). If any of those methods are defined for an object, it is said to be a descriptor.

None of those methods seem to be present in the class definition, so why is __init_ referred to as a descriptor?

Comment: For the record, the only reason it has this design is to allow a `Counter` to be initialized with a keyword argument named `self` without accidentally replacing the `self` instance in `__init__`; they had to accept positional varargs and manually extract the "real" `self` so it had no external name that could be overridden by a keyword argument. You can't actually trigger this error unless you're manually calling `__init__` (and doing so without using `super` in a subclass, which would pass it implicitly, just like regular construction).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In python, **all** functions are descriptors (including `__init__`).  This is actually how they know what `self` is when they're used in a class.  For example, I can define a function (`foo`) and then when I look at it's methods, I'll see that `foo` has a `__get__` method which makes it adhere to the descriptor protocol:

```
>>> def foo():
...   pass
... 
>>> dir(foo)
['__annotations__', '__call__', '__class__', '__closure__', '__code__', '__defaults__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__get__', '__getattribute__', '__globals__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__kwdefaults__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__name__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__qualname__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__']
>>> '__get__' in dir(foo)
True
```

So the terminology used there is at least *accurate*.  It could be debated whether that's the best term to use...

I might have called it a "Bound method" instead of a descriptor, but in python3.x, the distinction between regular functions, bound methods and unbound methods becomes a little more muddy (unbound methods *are* regular functions in python3.x)...

---

Of course, I could use a different type of descriptor to initialize my `Counter` subclass ...

```
class MyDescriptor(object):
    def __get__(self, inst, cls):
        # This is a really useless descriptor!
        return Counter.__init__.__get__(inst, cls)

class MyCounter(Counter):
    __init__ = MyDescriptor()
```

and throw an error, then the error message would be more accurate that way, but this is a pretty crazy case that I wouldn't expect to happen very frequently.

To really know what Raymond was thinking when he wrote that code, I suppose you'd have to ask him (or go spelunking in the hg commit history and hope he mentioned it in a commit message).

Comment: I don't understand your answer and I double don't understand how it falls in line with the cited documentation. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Ah I missed that it was the function that had defined \_\_get__, not Counter. Thanks.

Comment: Related: Why refer to a function as a descriptor when it would be more descriptive (no pun intended) to just call it a function?

Comment: @DavisYoshida -- I suppose you could set `__init__` to any type of descriptor that you wanted.  It wouldn't _have_ to be a function (though it pretty much always is).

Comment: @timgeb -- All I'm saying is that `__init__` is a function (usually) and all functions are descriptors by virtue of the fact that they have `__get__` methods.

Comment: Thanks, I find your updated answer easier to understand.